# Context Menu não aparece no ícone de bandeja quando eu clico com o mouse

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt-5

Estou criando uma aplicação que tem um ícone de bandeja (`QSystemTrayIcon`) e quero que ele tenha algumas opções para controlar a aplicação. Para isso eu criei a classe abaixo:

```
class QTrayIcon(object):

    def __init__(self, title, icon, parent = None):
        self.__trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(parent = parent)
        self.__context_menu = QMenu()
        self.__trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.__context_menu)

        self.set_icon(icon)
        self.set_title(title)

    def add_option(self, text, function):
        option = QAction(text)
        option.triggered.connect(function)
        self.__context_menu.addAction(option)

    def set_icon(self, icon):
        self.__icon = QIcon(icon)
        self.__trayIcon.setIcon(self.__icon)
        self.__trayIcon.setVisible(True)

    def set_title(self, title):
        self.__trayIcon.setToolTip(title)
```

O ícone de bandeja é criado normalmente. O problema é que quando eu clico com o botão direito do mouse para abrir o "context menu", nada acontece. Ou melhor, é possível notar um pontinho bem pequeno — aproximadamente 2 pixels — aparecendo e sumindo rapidamente. Abaixo está o código de exemplo para executar a classe:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMenu, QSystemTrayIcon, QApplication
import sys

application = QApplication(sys.argv)
tray = QTrayIcon("Application name", "My icon.ico", application)
tray.add_option("Primeira opção", lambda: None)
tray.add_option("Segunda opção", lambda: None)
application.exec_()
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Revisei a classe várias vezes e não consigo ver erro algum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que os objetos de `QAction`, no final da execução do método, perdem suas referências e são coletados pelo Garbage Collector.

Para solucionar o problema, você deve instanciar cada um dos objetos, a fim de manter a referência dos mesmos. No seu caso, armazene cada objeto em uma lista. Veja o código abaixo:

```
class QTrayIcon(object):

    __options = []

    def __init__(self, title, icon, parent = None):
        self.__trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(parent = parent)
        self.__context_menu = QMenu()
        self.__trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.__context_menu)

        self.set_icon(icon)
        self.set_title(title)

    def add_option(self, text, function):
        option = QAction(text)
        option.triggered.connect(function)
        self.__context_menu.addAction(option)
        self.__options.append(option)

    def set_icon(self, icon):
        self.__icon = QIcon(icon)
        self.__trayIcon.setIcon(self.__icon)
        self.__trayIcon.setVisible(True)

    def set_title(self, title):
        self.__trayIcon.setToolTip(title)
```